# Return Only Primary Keys That Share The Same Foriegn Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We're struggling with a lightweight way to reduce results in a larger population of search results by excluding rows that don't match ALL of the foreign keys in a second table.

For example, we have a mapping table that matches documents to tags where each document can have an unlimited number of tag relationships:

```
DocID | TagID
12 | 1
12 | 2
34 | 1
53 | 1
53 | 4
66 | 1
66 | 2
67 | 3
```

We're building a table in our SPROC based on a list of tagIDs passed in by the user, so we have a second table that looks like this:

```
TagID
1
2
```

What we'd like to do is return only the rows from the first table that contain a match on every value in the second table, effectively an "and" query.  So if the user passes in tag values 1 & 2 we want to return DocID 12 and 66.  Right now our joins return essentially an "or" result, so values 1 & 2 would return DocIDs 12, 34, and 66.

We're currently stuck with MS SQL 2008R2.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `group by` and `having` and a twist:

```
select docid
from firsttable t1 join
     secondtable t2
     on t1.tagid = t2.tagid
group by docid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from secondtable);
```

You may need `count(distinct)` if either table could have duplicates.

Comment: You are correct, this is definitely a dup and I promise I searched first.  Great answers by both.  Thanks.

Comment: @ButterDuck . . . This question may be a dup, but not of that question.  You are storing your list in a table.